# Regex Query to get string value

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex query that would allow me to retrieve a value from a string
here are examples of my string:

```
home.aspx?StudyID=0020101&aa=72
randompage.aspx?studyid=3023603&aa=40
myconfig.aspx?studyid=0021600&aa=40
```

I need to get the numerical value of the `'studyid'` variable, please note that the name of the page will change so simply doing the substring and counting char spaces didn't work

I unfortunately cannot use request.querystring method as this string is stored in the database and a select statement will be used for running this regex query

Thanks

Comment: What programming language or program are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
/studyid=(\d{7})/i
```

Comment: I would recommend not using the {7} quantifier. I wouldn't recommend this because he hasn't stated how long a studyID could be. If it is longer then 7 chars then your regex blows up.

Comment: @george: if the value is any different than that, then OP needs to provide relevant examples.

Comment: Yes generally it is 7 chars, so should be ok

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use can use parenthesis to capture values in regex.

Therefore, you can match the string to `studyid=(\d+)` and get the value using $1.

Answer (score 0):

```
/studyid=([^&]*)&/i
```

The first group will contain the variable.